# only allow white space in between characters

Tags: regex, c#-3.0

I only want to allow a-z, A-Z and space in between characters. For this I am using following regex, problem is that it allows the leading and trailing spaces also. Can this be adjusted to not allow leading or trailing white space.

```
[a-zA-Z\\ \\\']*
```

**examples**
'prince charles' should pass
' prince charles' should fail due to leading whitespace
'prince charles ' should fail due to trailing whitespace

Comment: Why do you have quotes in there? And why are you escaping your whitespace?

Comment: Can you give inputs and postive/negative outputs

Comment: Give some example strings and example expected output. Your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want the entire string to match, or do you want to pick out multiple matches. That is, given "  this is a test 123 foobar", do you expect to get back "this is a test" and "foobar"? Or do you expect that string to fail validation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To dis-allow leading and trailing whitespace, you can use:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z])?$
```

Comment: @PaulSnow. Time to show us some sample strings that should match, and some that shouldn't match.

Comment: @PaulSnow. I guess you didn't add anchors. Try it now.

Comment: hmmm; still same issue. Can you try running it see if works for you?

Comment: @RohitJain What's the difference between this & `^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z ]+[a-zA-Z]+)?$`

Answer (score 2):

Word boundaries. It's as simple as that:

```
^\b[a-zA-Z ]*\b$
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Removed leading whitespace, but I was able to throw in as many trailing whitespaces as I wanted. https://regexr.com/

Comment: A trailing whitespace will prevent /\b$/ from matching. Do you see why?